# HealthKit Blood Oxygen SPO2

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

With the series 6 Apple Watch, you can now get a measure of your SP02, hemoglobin content in your blood oxygen. The health app on the iPhone shows you all the measurements in the Respiratory section. This is a critical component for COVID patients.

I have not been able to find anyway to access this information programatically.

I have checked all HKObjectTypes in the latest Apple documentation. Is this information currently available to iOS developers?

Any information would be of great use as several researchers are requesting it.

Comment: I don't really know much about biology or HealthKit, but is this related to what you're looking for: [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/1615377-oxygensaturation)?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am being told that this is the same as Oxygen Saturation.Here is the code I use to query HK for Oxygen Saturation:

```
    // Get SPO2
func getOxygenSaturation()
{
    // Type is SPO2 SDNN
    let osType:HKQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.oxygenSaturation)!

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date.distantPast, end: Date(), options: .strictEndDate)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    let osUnit:HKUnit = HKUnit(from: "%")

    
    let osQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: osType,
                                 predicate: predicate,
                                 limit: 10,
                                 sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
        guard error == nil else { print("error"); return }
        
        // Get the array of results from the sample query
        let sampleArray:[HKSample]? = results!
        
        // Loop through the array of rsults
        for (_, sample) in sampleArray!.enumerated()
        {
            // Be sure something is there
            if let currData:HKQuantitySample = sample as? HKQuantitySample
            {
                let os: Double = (currData.quantity.doubleValue(for: osUnit) * 100.0)
                let d1: Date = currData.startDate
                let str1 = SwiftLib.returnDateAndTimeWithTZ(date: d1, info: self.info!)

                Dispatch.DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.tvOxygenValue.text = String(format: "%.0f%@", os, "%");
                    self.tvOxygenDate.text = str1
                    //print("\(os)");
                }
            }
        }
        
        print("Done")
        self.loadAndDisplayActivityInformation()
    }

    healthStore!.execute(osQuery)
}
```

Comment: and what is the solution to get the Oxygen Saturation programatically ?